# HUGO How to use pagination inside terms page?

Tags: pagination, hugo, static-site

I'm trying to use a pagination inside a terms page (e.g. `/layouts/tags/terms.html`) because I got many tags.

And I also want to display all my tags sorted by popularity. For the last point, I did:

```
{{ range .Data.Terms.ByCount}}
...
{{ end }}
```

And it works fine.

I tried:

1)

```
{{ range .Data.Terms.ByCount}}
{{ range .Paginator.Pages }}
...
{{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

But I got "can't evaluate field Paginator in type hugolib.OrderedTaxonomyEntry" ERROR.

2)

```
{{ range .Paginator.Pages }}
{{ range .Data.Terms.ByCount}}
...
{{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

I got no error but no posts are displayed, only the pagination is there.

3)

```
{{ $paginator := .Paginate .Data.Terms.ByCount }}
{{ range $paginator.Pages }}
...

{{ end }}
```

I got: "error calling Paginate: cannot convert type hugolib.OrderedTaxonomy to Pages" ERROR.

I tried many others things but I couldn't figure out how to do display all my posts by popularity with a pagination in my taxonomy `terms.html` page.

Do you have more idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from somewhere else; it is:

```
{{ $topaginate := slice }}

{{ range $k, $v := .Data.Terms.ByCount}}
{{ $topaginate = $topaginate | append  (site.GetPage (print $.Data.Plural "/" $v.Term )) }}
{{ end }}

{{ range (.Paginate $topaginate).Pages }}
{{ . }}
{{ end }}
```

Comment: Something that should be simple and ready to be used out-of-box has to be manually workaround by the users because Hugo Community (and its developers - especially the leading ones) are too picky about it. Thank you very much for the solution :)

Answer (score 2):

In your `terms.html` page put the following code. It should work.

```
{{ range  .Paginator.Pages }}
  {{ .Title }}: {{ .RelPermalink }}
{{ end }}
```

But since you want it sorted, you probably need something like this.

```
{{ range .Paginator.Pages.ByDate }}
  {{ .Title }}: {{ .RelPermalink }}
{{ end }}
```

You can sort using other parameters. Check the full list [here](https://gohugo.io/templates/lists/).

You wanted to sort by popularity. I'm not sure what how you're defining popularity. But if `popularity` is a front matter variable, you can sort by it with the following.

```
{{ range (.Pages.ByParam "popularity") }}
  <!-- ... -->
{{ end }}
```

Comment: What I mean by popularity is the amount of posts tags contain. I used the term "popularity" because the official Hugo doc says it (see https://gohugo.io/variables/taxonomy/#taxonomy-terms-page-variables). Anyway I got the answer somewhere else and I'll post the response.